# How to maximize the drop odds of the Essences in Diablo II?

Tags: diablo-ii

How to maximize drop odds of **Twisted Essence of Suffering**, **Charged Essence of Hatred**, **Burning Essence of Terror** and **Festering Essence of Destruction**?

Do you want to increase or decrease the /players setting (or have more/less players in game) and/or increase or decrease magic find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MF only affects the quality (normal/magic/rare/set/unique) of an item. There is no evidence to support that MF or increase of player characters has anything to do with essence drop rates.

I'll put the drop rates below in case you want them. The drop rate actually changes based on if you're killing them for the first time or not.

At players 1 drop, chance to drop 1 essence:

Andariel Non-Quest: 1:14
Andariel Quest: 1:9

Duriel Non-Quest: 1:7
Duriel Quest: 1:5

Mephisto Non-Quest: 1:17
Mephisto Quest: 1:15

Diablo Non-Quest: 1:17
Diablo Quest: 1:15

Baal Non-Quest: 1:17
Baal Quest: 1:15

Comment: what is "Non-Q" and "Q" ?

Comment: @arghtype Quest and non quest. Basically if you're killing them for the first time or not. Sorry I was just lazy, I'll fix the answer.

Comment: So players setting doesn't matter? Thinking of the countess, summoner and nihlatak who have increased chances to drop keys of terror/hate/destruction with an increased player setting, it would seem the same with essences.

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer I know, all I can say is... D2. I think the keys have a set drop rate and can be manipulated MF but these essences are unlike all other items in the game.

Comment: You change from colons to division slashes after the first.  When I see 1:14 I think that is the odds so I have 1/15 chance to get it.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah my bad, it means the same thing, just different notation. I edited the answer to use 'ratio' notation in all instances. I didn't notice before, thanks!

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Either way, while playing it really feels like player setting and MF have no effect and it seems to be close to your listed odds. Your MF argument makes absolute sense and brings that out of question. But still I haven't found a source that confirms that the player setting has no effect on the essence drop. Maybe some mf calculator can help here [Test with 0% MF, p1 -> 0% MF, p8]? Haven't found the essences on indiablo mf calc and silospen mf calc though

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer Yeah my answer basically resides in "community observation" with the MF rules about the essences. The only thing that has been officially set in stone is that the drop rates are increased for first kill.